# reading several text files in a same script

Tags: matlab

I have a question for the reading of multiple files `.txt` in the same times and same script. I have a principal folder `Matlab` in which there are 7 subfolders `Folder1 to Folder 7` in which of them there is un document `file.txt`.

I would like to read each of 'file.txt' in a script that I run in the curent folder `Matlab`. is there a fast way to do this? Or am I forced to do `load file.txt` for each folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dir` to list all your Folder. Then you can create the path of your file for each folder and load this file.

```
folder = dir('Folder*'); %list all the folder whose name start with 'Folder'
for ii = 1:length(folder)
    s{ii} = fullfile(folder(ii).name,'text.txt'); %create the path for each file
    load(s{ii});
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In a for loop you can create the folder name:

```
for i = 1:n
  name = ['folder',int2str(i)]
% then you can open and read the file
  fileID = fopen([name,'\file.txt'])
  data = fread(fileID)
% Don't forget to close the file
  fclose(fileID)
end
```